# How to redirect in htaccess based on query parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to strip query parameters then redirect to main page when the word "utm" will occur in the URL, do you have any ideas how to do it?

for example:

http://example.com/?utm=cxzcxz

on http://example.com/

```
BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @starkeen I don't see any effects to go, these rewrite rules doesn't work